# How to set default checked/enabled background graphic option in print preview using window.print

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, windows

I want to be default checked the background graphic option in the print preview window by using javascript or CSS?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Below option help me to archive in chrome, but not in Firefox.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    * {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; /*Chrome, Safari */
        color-adjust: exact !important;  /*Firefox*/
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It work when I put above code inside print section. Thanks!